# Ruby: hide WEBrick httpd version

Tags: version, hide, webrick

I'm using OpenVZ Web Panel to manage my VPS servers and when I scanned my server with nmap I saw:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE      VERSION
22/tcp   open     ssh          OpenSSH 6.0p1 Debian 4 (protocol 2.0)
135/tcp  filtered msrpc
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
3000/tcp open     http         **WEBrick httpd 1.3.1 (Ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08))**
Service Info: OS: Linux; CPE: cpe:/o:linux:kernel
```

How do I hide the `**WEBrick httpd 1.3.1 (Ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08))**`?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party as I am, I encountered this question so I might as well answer it. I don't find your requirements entirely clear, so I'll give a conditional answer:

- If you don't want WEBrick to be visible at all, remove or comment its virtual host entry
- If you don't want WEBrick to be running on `:3000`, you have two choices:

  - Change the virtual host entry so that it listens on `:80` instead
  - Put [nginx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nginx/ReverseProxy) in front of it, proxying `somedomain:3000` to `127.0.0.1:80` and change WEBrick's virtual host entry so that it listens on `127.0.0.1:80` (you will need a domain name pointed at this machine)
- If you want WEBrick to be running but only accessible locally, change its virtual host entry so that it listens on `127.0.0.1:3000`

You *cannot* have WEBrick running and publicly accessible without `nmap` being able to discover it, because `nmap` discovers it the same way any client discovers it: by attempting to establish a connection with the indicated IP address and port.